# Getting error with the x:datatype in xaml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

My xaml code

```
 <Page x:Class="WindowsApp2.Views.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:Behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
  xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
  xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
  xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="using:WindowsApp2.Views"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:vm="using:WindowsApp2.ViewModels" mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
   <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Detail,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate 
                x:DataType="vm:Details">
                <TextBox Margin="200,200,0,0"
     Text="{x:Bind name,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</RelativePanel>
```

My MainPageViewModel.cs

```
 using Template10.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Template10.Services.NavigationService;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using WindowsApp2.Views;
namespace WindowsApp2.ViewModels
 {

public class Detail
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
}

public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            Value = "Designtime value";
        }

    Details = new List<Detail>();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            Detail d = new Detail();
            d.name = "kalp"+i.ToString();
            d.pass = "1234"+i.ToString();
            Details.Add(d);
        }
    }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
 }
```

Now My problem is that i am getting the error "The name "Detail" does not exist in the namespace "using:WindowsApp2.ViewModels".    My Detail class is defined in the namespace   WindowsApp2.ViewModels . So what is the problem here.
**NOTE:I deleted some code that is not related to this error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are describing is a side effect of an invalid binding that can't be compiled.

You are trying to bind to a view model property `Detail`, which indeed does not exist. What you certainly want is to bind to the `Details` property instead.

So replace

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Detail, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

with

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Details, Mode=OneWay}">
```

This does of course also require that there is a

```
public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; }
```

property in your MainPage class.

Note also that a `TwoWay` binding on the `ItemsSource` property doesn't make sense. It should instead be `OneWay`, or probably the default `OneTime`.